# cannot install npm packages for react native; might a proxy issue;

Tags: react-native, npm, proxy, npm-install

I cannot set up react native environment as I cannot install npm.
it shows some proxy error but tried all proxy solutions which I found on the internet, nothing works.

[image]

Comment: try this "npm init awsoproj".

Comment: error is clear, the latest version is not allowed to add Capital letters in the project name, try with all small letters.

Comment: check and let me know if your error is fixed.\

Comment: i cannot install npm itself to go on to npm init step

Comment: I know, what is the issue and I can fix it, I have the same issue yesterday and fixed it. can we check it together?

Comment: sure. i have posted the picture of the error i am getting